# Oracle SQL query times in one line

Tags: sql, oracle

I apologize in advance for any formatting issues.

Here is some sample data.

[image]

Here is what I would like to produce:

[image]

Here is what I get when I use a series of case when statements

[image]

Any coding help is much appreciated.

Comment: Edit you question and add the query you are using.

Comment: Please don't post images of data or code. Instead, include the code and data as formatted text. [See this page for formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Sounds good, thanks @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica.

Comment: I have to chuckle at the thumbs down here.  Cant imagine giving someone a thumbs down for asking an honest question.  But I do appreciate everyone's feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what the PIVOT clause was created for:

```sql
-- sample data:
with t(id, quarter, sales) as (
   select 1,1,13 from dual union all
   select 1,2,14 from dual union all
   select 1,3,21 from dual union all
   select 1,4,17 from dual union all
   select 2,1,11 from dual union all
   select 2,2,23 from dual union all
   select 2,3,18 from dual union all
   select 2,4,19 from dual 
)
-- query:
select *
from t
pivot(
  sum(sales) 
  for Quarter in (
        1 as Q1
       ,2 as Q2
       ,3 as Q3
       ,4 as Q4)
);

        ID         Q1         Q2         Q3         Q4
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         13         14         21         17
         2         11         23         18         19
```

Answer (score 1):

You need aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when quarter = 1 then sales end) as q1_sales,
       sum(case when quarter = 2 then sales end) as q2_sales,
       sum(case when quarter = 3 then sales end) as q3_sales,
       sum(case when quarter = 4 then sales end) as q4_sales
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that seems to have solved the problem!